# Half violin plot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Recently matplotlib has added a native support for [violin plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot). What I want to do is *half*-violin plot as [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/EnricoGiampieri/dataplot/blob/master/statplot.ipynb). I guess that it can be done changing the `body` the function is returning. Do you know how to plot half violin plot as in the example but using the new function from matplotlib?

Comment: seaborn does paired half violins, might be easier to start there: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn-dev/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html

Comment: The Stanford link in the comments appears to be dead.

Comment: @PhilB  Seaborn now has its doc pages at pydata: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here simplify modifying the patches, clipping the values on the right or left

```
data1 = (np.random.normal(0, 1, size=10000), np.random.normal(0, 2, size=10000))
data2 = (np.random.normal(1, 1, size=10000), np.random.normal(1, 2, size=10000))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 7))

v1 = ax.violinplot(data1, points=100, positions=np.arange(0, len(data1)),
               showmeans=False, showextrema=False, showmedians=False)
for b in v1['bodies']:
    # get the center
    m = np.mean(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0])
    # modify the paths to not go further right than the center
    b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0] = np.clip(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0], -np.inf, m)
    b.set_color('r')

v2 = ax.violinplot(data2, points=100, positions=np.arange(0, len(data2)), 
               showmeans=False, showextrema=False, showmedians=False)

for b in v2['bodies']:
    # get the center
    m = np.mean(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0])
    # modify the paths to not go further left than the center
    b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0] = np.clip(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0], m, np.inf)
    b.set_color('b')

ax.legend([v1['bodies'][0],v2['bodies'][0]],['data1', 'data2'])
```

[image]

Comment: with some comments, it may help... TY