# half (not split!) violin plots in seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

Currently seaborn offers [functionality for split violinplots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) by setting `split=True`, according to a `hue` variable.  I would like to make a 'half' violin plot, i.e. a plot where half of each violin is omitted. Such a plot depicts something similar to a pdf for each continuous variable, plotted on one side of each vertical line of each categorical variable only.

I have managed to trick `seaborn` to plot this with an extra data point outside the plotted range of values and an extra dummy hue, but I would like to know if this can be done without actually altering the dataset, e.g. within `sns.violinplot()` arguments.

For instance, this graph:

[image]

Was created by this snippet:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load dataset from seaborn
datalist = sns.get_dataset_names()
dataset_name = 'iris'
if dataset_name in datalist:
    df = sns.load_dataset(dataset_name)
else:
    print("Dataset with name: " + dataset_name + " was not found in the available datasets online by seaborn.")

# prepare data
df2 = df.append([-999,-999,-999,-999,'setosa'])
df2['huecol'] = 0.0
df2['huecol'].iloc[-1]= -999

# plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
sns.violinplot(x='species',y="sepal_width",
            split=True, hue ='huecol', inner = 'quartile',
            palette="pastel", data=df2, legend=False)
plt.title('iris')

# remove hue legend
leg = plt.gca().legend()
leg.remove()
plt.ylim([1,5.0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Using matplotlib instead of seaborn, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29781988/

Comment: What's the problem with temporarily modifying your data to generate a plot?

Comment: @jpp perhaps a ridge plot could be made to work https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not necessary to modify the data:

```
ax = sns.violinplot(
    data=tips,
    x="day", y="total_bill", hue=True,
    hue_order=[True, False], split=True,
)
ax.legend_ = None
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hack, imo should be the accepted answer! :) Glad I scrolled all the way down ^^

Comment: ```hue_order``` does not work with hue as boolean argument for me

Answer (score 9):

The answer is simply, no, it's not possible with seaborn without tricking it into thinking there is a `hue` present.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29781988/) shows how to do it in matplotlib and in principle the same can be applied to seaborn violinplots as well, namely to cut out half of the violin path.

Comment: Thank you for your link, but could you please provide the code that would do the same with `seaborn`? Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: Actually it should not be the same, but just half of the violin. The plots at your link are two sided violins, which is not what the TS asked for.

Comment: @SergeyZakharov The code in the question shows how one can do it with seaborn. I suppose I do not need to repeat it. The linked matplotlib code produces two sides of a violin separately; I suppose it's clear that if you want only half a violin, you just leave out one of the two parts of the answer.

Comment: Now I understand how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for a solution similar to this but did not find anything satisfactory. I ended up calling [seaborn.kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) multiple times as violinplot is essentially a one-sided kernel density plot.

#### Example

*Function definition for `categorical_kde_plot` below*

```
categorical_kde_plot(
    df,
    variable="tip",
    category="day",
    category_order=["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
    horizontal=False,
)
```

[image]

with `horizontal=True`, the output would look like:

[image]

### Code

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def categorical_kde_plot(
    df,
    variable,
    category,
    category_order=None,
    horizontal=False,
    rug=True,
    figsize=None,
):
    """Draw a categorical KDE plot

    Parameters
    ----------
    df: pd.DataFrame
        The data to plot
    variable: str
        The column in the `df` to plot (continuous variable)
    category: str
        The column in the `df` to use for grouping (categorical variable)
    horizontal: bool
        If True, draw density plots horizontally. Otherwise, draw them
        vertically.
    rug: bool
        If True, add also a sns.rugplot.
    figsize: tuple or None
        If None, use default figsize of (7, 1*len(categories))
        If tuple, use that figsize. Given to plt.subplots as an argument.
    """
    if category_order is None:
        categories = list(df[category].unique())
    else:
        categories = category_order[:]

    figsize = (7, 1.0 * len(categories))

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(
        nrows=len(categories) if horizontal else 1,
        ncols=1 if horizontal else len(categories),
        figsize=figsize[::-1] if not horizontal else figsize,
        sharex=horizontal,
        sharey=not horizontal,
    )

    for i, (cat, ax) in enumerate(zip(categories, axes)):
        sns.kdeplot(
            data=df[df[category] == cat],
            x=variable if horizontal else None,
            y=None if horizontal else variable,
            # kde kwargs
            bw_adjust=0.5,
            clip_on=False,
            fill=True,
            alpha=1,
            linewidth=1.5,
            ax=ax,
            color="lightslategray",
        )

        keep_variable_axis = (i == len(fig.axes) - 1) if horizontal else (i == 0)

        if rug:
            sns.rugplot(
                data=df[df[category] == cat],
                x=variable if horizontal else None,
                y=None if horizontal else variable,
                ax=ax,
                color="black",
                height=0.025 if keep_variable_axis else 0.04,
            )

        _format_axis(
            ax,
            cat,
            horizontal,
            keep_variable_axis=keep_variable_axis,
        )

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def _format_axis(ax, category, horizontal=False, keep_variable_axis=True):

    # Remove the axis lines
    ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

    if horizontal:
        ax.set_ylabel(None)
        lim = ax.get_ylim()
        ax.set_yticks([(lim[0] + lim[1]) / 2])
        ax.set_yticklabels([category])
        if not keep_variable_axis:
            ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
            ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
    else:
        ax.set_xlabel(None)
        lim = ax.get_xlim()
        ax.set_xticks([(lim[0] + lim[1]) / 2])
        ax.set_xticklabels([category])
        if not keep_variable_axis:
            ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
            ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

    categorical_kde_plot(
        df,
        variable="tip",
        category="day",
        category_order=["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
        horizontal=True,
    )
```

Comment: This is a nice answer but it's WAY overkill to roll your own for loop here when this approach (column facet with kde plots on the y axes) is straightforward with `displot`.