# using matplotlib, not seaborn, make equal area violin plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, violin-plot

I'm trying to plot some data as split violins, for which I adapted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776114/half-violin-plot), to get a first pass. The issue with this is that the parameter controlling the violin sizes is a 'width' which means that distributions that are narrow will look materially smaller than distributions that are wide (they'll have less visual weight). I do not want to use Seaborn (I'm actually not using categorical data, for one thing), but it has a handy feature that makes the plotted area of violins equal. Does anyone have any ideas about how I could customize matplotlib's violinplot to do this?

Comment: I don't think matplotlib has that functionality currently. One option would be to do some pre-processing to calculate a weighting for each violin, which you could pass in as the `widths` parameter to scale each violin to the correct area