# Creating violin plots for different groups and using two different y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I currently have the following plot:

[image: Violin plot]

The problem is, since the shortrun violin plots are around -0.1 and the longrun violin plots around -0.5, the readability of the graph is far less than it could be. Therefore, I wanted to create a second y-axis that is connected to the shortrun violin plots.

I'd like to create a violin plot using two different y-axis while plotting multiple violin plots for multiple labels on the x-axis.

I am trying to create a violin plot. Specifically, for 3 different risk groups I want to plot a violin plot for longrun and shortrun elasticities each (so 6 violins in total). Since the longrun elasticities are of a different order of magnitude than the shortrun elasticities, I want to use a different y-scale for long- and short-run.

This is what I came up so far:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(50)

# generate some random data
data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000), columns=['Value'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=0.1, size=100), columns=['Value'])
data3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=1, size=1000), columns=['Value'])
data4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=0.1, size=100), columns=['Value'])
data5 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=1, size=1000), columns=['Value'])
data6 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=0.1, size=100), columns=['Value'])

# create the figure and the axes
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# create the first set of violin plots on ax1
sns.violinplot(data=[data1['Value'], data3['Value'], data5['Value']], ax=ax1, palette=['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green'])

# set the label and the color of the left y-axis
ax1.set_ylabel('Data 1', color='tab:blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:blue')

# create the second axes sharing the x-axis with ax1
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# create the second set of violin plots on ax2
sns.violinplot(data=[data2['Value'], data4['Value'], data6['Value']], ax=ax2, palette=['tab:red', 'tab:purple', 'tab:brown'])

# set the label and the color of the right y-axis
ax2.set_ylabel('Data 2', color='tab:red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red')

# set the x-axis tick locations and labels
ax1.set_xticks([0, 1, 2])
ax1.set_xticklabels(['No Risk', 'Double Risk', 'Expenditure Risk'])

# set the x-axis label and the title
ax1.set_xlabel('Risk Level')
ax1.set_title('Three Sets of Violin Plots with Different Y-Axes')

# adjust the position of the axes
ax2.set_position([0.13, 0.1, 0.775, 0.8])

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I want the two violin plots corresponding to each risk group to be placed next to each other instead of on top of each other. How can I fix this.

I tried this before but I dont know how to combine it with the seaborn package:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate some random data
data1 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
data2 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=100)
data3 = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=1, size=1000)
data4 = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=0.1, size=100)

# create the figure and the axes
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# create the first set of violin plots on ax1
vp1 = ax1.violinplot([data1, data3], positions=[0, 1], widths=0.5)
vp1['bodies'][0].set_facecolor('tab:blue')
vp1['bodies'][1].set_facecolor('tab:blue')

# set the label and the color of the left y-axis
ax1.set_ylabel('Data 1', color='tab:blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:blue')

# create the second axes sharing the x-axis with ax1
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# create the second set of violin plots on ax2
vp2 = ax2.violinplot([data2, data4], positions=[0.5, 1.5], widths=0.5)
vp2['bodies'][0].set_facecolor('tab:red')
vp2['bodies'][1].set_facecolor('tab:red')

# set the label and the color of the right y-axis
ax2.set_ylabel('Data 2', color='tab:red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red')

# set the x-axis tick locations and labels
ax1.set_xticks([0.25, 1.25])
ax1.set_xticklabels(['No Risk', 'Double Risk'])

# set the x-axis label and the title
ax1.set_xlabel('Risk Level')
ax1.set_title('Two Sets of Violin Plots with Different Y-Axes')

# adjust the position of the axes
ax2.set_position([0.13, 0.1, 0.775, 0.8])

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how to both separate a dataset into two vertical ranges (twinning the x axis) and customizing the violin plots. The code snippet you provided at the end of the question already creates two vertical ranges, so the point of this response is to provide insight about customizing the violin plots alongside having two vertical ranges.

This can be done easily without the seaborn package and just using matplotlib (see [customizing violin plots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/customized_violin.html)). To illustrate, here is a small function that shows some customization, but the matplotlib documentation can extend this function further.

```
def custom_violin(ax, data, pos, fc='b', ec='k', alpha=0.7, percentiles=[25, 50, 75], side="both", scatter_kwargs={}, violin_kwargs={}):
    """Customized violin plot.
    ax: axes.Axes, The axes to plot to
    data: 1D array like, The data to plot
    pos: float, The position on the x-axis where the violin should be plotted
    fc: color, The facecolor of the violin
    ec: color, The edgecolor of the violin
    alpha: float, The transparancy of the violin
    percentiles: array like, The percentiles to be marked on the violin
    side: string, Which side(s) of the violin should be cut off. Options: 'left', 'right', 'both'
    scatter_kwargs: dict, Keyword arguments for the scatterplot
    violin_kwargs: dict, Keyword arguments for the violinplot"""

    parts = ax.violinplot(data, positions=[pos], **violin_kwargs)
    for pc in parts['bodies']:
        m = np.mean(pc.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0])
        if side == "left":
            points_x = pos - 0.05
            pc.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0] = np.clip(pc.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0], -np.inf, m)
        elif side == "right":
            points_x = pos + 0.05
            pc.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0] = np.clip(pc.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0], m, np.inf)
        else:
            points_x = pos
        pc.set_facecolor(fc)
        pc.set_edgecolor(ec)
        pc.set_alpha(alpha)

    perc = np.percentile(data, percentiles)
    for p in perc:
        ax.scatter(points_x, p, color=ec, zorder=3, **scatter_kwargs)
```

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# generate some random data
data1 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
data2 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=100)
data3 = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=1, size=1000)
data4 = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=0.1, size=100)

s_kwargs = {"s": 40, "marker": "_"}
v_kwargs = {"showextrema": False, "showmedians": False, "showmeans": False, "widths": 0.5}

# create the figure and the axes (left and right)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# create the first set of violin plots for the no risk data
custom_violin(ax1, data1, 0, 'tab:blue', 'tab:blue', 0.6, scatter_kwargs=s_kwargs, violin_kwargs=v_kwargs)
custom_violin(ax2, data2, 0.5, 'tab:red', 'tab:red', 0.6, scatter_kwargs=s_kwargs, violin_kwargs=v_kwargs)
ax1.set_ylabel('Data 1', color='tab:blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:blue')

# create the second set of violin plots on ax2
custom_violin(ax1, data3, 1, 'tab:blue', 'tab:blue', 0.6,  scatter_kwargs=s_kwargs, violin_kwargs=v_kwargs)
custom_violin(ax2, data4, 1.5, 'tab:red', 'tab:red', 0.6, scatter_kwargs=s_kwargs, violin_kwargs=v_kwargs)
ax2.set_ylabel('Data 2', color='tab:red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red')

# set the x-axis tick locations and labels
ax1.set_xticks([0.25, 1.25])
ax1.set_xticklabels(['No Risk', 'Double Risk'])
ax1.set_xlabel('Risk Level')
ax1.set_title('Two Sets of Violin Plots with Different Y-Axes')

# adjust the position of the axes
ax2.set_position([0.13, 0.1, 0.775, 0.8])

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: Symmetric Violin]

The function also allows you to plot the data using asymmetric violins (see [half violin plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29781988/21828280)) by specifying the "side" keyword. To apply this to the above example, one would specify left and right and keep the position constant.

```
# create the first set of violin plots for the no risk data
custom_violin(ax1, data1, 0, 'tab:blue', 'tab:blue', 0.6, side="left", scatter_kwargs=s_kwargs, violin_kwargs=v_kwargs)
custom_violin(ax2, data2, 0, 'tab:red', 'tab:red', 0.6, side="right", scatter_kwargs=s_kwargs, violin_kwargs=v_kwargs)
```

[image: Asymmetric Violin]

Answer (score 1):

- An option is to combine all of the dataframes into a single dataframe with common columns, using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), while using [`.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add appropriate identifying columns.

  - This is the case because `seaborn` works best with dataframes in a long form.
- [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with [`kind='violin'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) is the [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-functions-own-their-figure) version of the [axes-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#axes-level-functions-make-self-contained-plots) [`sns.violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html).
- The point of this visualization is to compare the distributions on a similar scale. The desired plot may confuse the comparison, as the sets relate to each other, which is not a good practice.

  - Violin plots depict summary statistics, and the density of each variable.
  - Rather than showing counts of data points that fall into bins or order statistics, violin plots use kernel density estimation (KDE) to compute an empirical distribution of the sample.
- `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`. The API specifically makes comparing groups of data easier. That said, there is only so much flexibility. For a truly customized plot, one should work directly with `matplotlib`.

  - [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.violinplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.violinplot.html) - [explicit API](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#the-explicit-api)
  - [`matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot.html) - [implicit API](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#the-implicit-api)
  - [Violin plot basics](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/violinplot.html)
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

### Imports and Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ordered list of the risks
risks = ['None', 'Double', 'Expenditure']

# combine dataframes from OP into one dataframe
df = pd.concat([data1.assign(Risk_Level='None').assign(Data=1), data3.assign(Risk_Level='Double').assign(Data=1), data5.assign(Risk_Level='Expenditure').assign(Data=1),
                data2.assign(Risk_Level='None').assign(Data=2), data4.assign(Risk_Level='Double').assign(Data=2), data6.assign(Risk_Level='Expenditure').assign(Data=2)], ignore_index=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_', ' ')
df['Risk Level'] = pd.Categorical(df['Risk Level'], risks, ordered=True)

# combine dataframes from OP into two dataframes
df1 = pd.concat([data1.assign(Risk_Level='None').assign(Data=1), data3.assign(Risk_Level='Double').assign(Data=1), data5.assign(Risk_Level='Expenditure').assign(Data=1)], ignore_index=True)
df2 = pd.concat([data2.assign(Risk_Level='None').assign(Data=2), data4.assign(Risk_Level='Double').assign(Data=2), data6.assign(Risk_Level='Expenditure').assign(Data=2)], ignore_index=True)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace('_', ' ')
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('_', ' ')
df1['Risk Level'] = pd.Categorical(df1['Risk Level'], risks, ordered=True)
df2['Risk Level'] = pd.Categorical(df2['Risk Level'], risks, ordered=True)
```

### Option 1: `seaborn` and `pandas`

- Using the single combined dataframe, `df`, and plotting to a single yaxis, allows for easy comparison of both sets of data, with the same scale.

```py
# the figure level plot 
g = sns.catplot(data=df, x='Risk Level', y='Value', hue='Data', kind='violin', height=3.5, aspect=2.5)
```

[image]

- Adapting [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76188977/7758804) to use the data from the OP results in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeNgU.png), which compresses the violins. However, calling the plot function for each combined dataframe, `df1` and `df2`, results in violins scaled similarly to plotting them on in separate plots.

```py
fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = ax0.twinx()

hue_order = df.Data.unique()

sns.violinplot(df1, x="Risk Level", y='Value', hue="Data", hue_order=hue_order, ax=ax0)
sns.violinplot(df2, x="Risk Level", y='Value', hue="Data", hue_order=hue_order, ax=ax1)
```

[image]

- Show the two groups in separate subplots

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5), tight_layout=True, sharey=True)

sns.violinplot(data=df.query('Data == 1'), x='Risk Level', y='Value', ax=ax1)
sns.violinplot(data=df.query('Data == 2'), x='Risk Level', y='Value', ax=ax2)

ax1.set(title='Data Set 1')
ax2.set(title='Data Set 2', ylabel='')
ax2.tick_params(left=False)
```

[image]

#### `sharey=False`

[image]

- If the density comparison is not important, use a boxplot.

```py
g = sns.catplot(data=df, x='Risk Level', y='Value', hue='Data', kind='box', height=3.5, aspect=2.5)
```

[image]

---

### Option 2: `matplotlib` and `pandas`

- Use `.groupby` to iterate through each group and plot the violin at at a specific tick location on the x-axis.

#### Using a single dataframe, `df`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
for i, ((rl, d), dfg) in enumerate(df.groupby(['Risk Level', 'Data'])):
    ax.violinplot(dfg.Value, positions=[i])

# add figure customizations
_ = ax.set_xticks([0.5, 2.5, 4.5], risks)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Using a dataframe, `df1` & `df2`, for each time period and `twinx`

```py
# create the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# iterate through each group and plot the data on on the even xticks
for i, ((rl, d), dfg) in zip(range(0, 7, 2), df1.groupby(['Risk Level', 'Data'])):
    vp1 = ax.violinplot(dfg.Value, positions=[i], showextrema=False)
    vp1['bodies'][0].set_facecolor('tab:blue')
    vp1['bodies'][0].set_edgecolor('k')

# add the secondary axes
ax2 = ax.twinx()

# iterate through each group and plot the data on on the odd xticks
for i, ((rl, d), dfg) in zip(range(1, 7, 2), df2.groupby(['Risk Level', 'Data'])):
    vp2 = ax2.violinplot(dfg.Value, positions=[i], showextrema=False)
    vp2['bodies'][0].set_facecolor('tab:red')
    vp2['bodies'][0].set_edgecolor('k')

# add figure customizations
_ = ax.set_xticks([0.5, 2.5, 4.5], risks)

ax.set_xlabel('Risk Level', labelpad=10)
ax.set_title('Two Sets of Violin Plots with Different Y-Axes')

ax.set_ylabel('Data 1', color='tab:blue')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:blue')

ax2.set_ylabel('Data 2', color='tab:red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### `df` view

```
      Value Risk Level  Data
0 -1.560352       None     1
1 -0.030978       None     1
2 -0.620928       None     1
3 -1.464580       None     1
4  1.411946       None     1
...
3295  2.013516  Expenditure     2
3296  2.085659  Expenditure     2
3297  1.998047  Expenditure     2
3298  2.055241  Expenditure     2
3299  2.080164  Expenditure     2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair amount of complexity in the other answers. I think a simpler way to approach this with `seaborn.violinplot` would be to call `violinplot` twice but use `hue` and `hue_order` to get the dodged effect:

```
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
f, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = ax0.twinx()
var_order = ["total_bill", "tip"]
for ax, var_name in zip([ax0, ax1], var_order):
    sns.violinplot(
        tips.assign(var=var_name),
        x="day", y=var_name, hue="var",
        hue_order=var_order, ax=ax
    )
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your code I get the error: 'Could not interpret input 'total_bill'.